# adding nested .git folders inside .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, .git-folder

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/ignoring-any-bin-directory-on-a-git-project) question shows how to use `.gitignore` to ignore various locations of `bin` folder inside your project. I've tried the same but with `.git` folder. I've put `.git/` inside my `.gitignore` then run `git init` and then `git add .` but with no luck. Git still complains about adding another repo inside current repo. My goal is to create one big repo which will contain multiple other repos (I do not need their git history, just files). I know about best practices and git modules etc. I'm just curious why it does not works with `.git/` but it works with `bin/`

**EDIT**
I' do not know what I did wrong at the time of writing this post but now it seems that it is working. I have empty `.gitignore` and if I issue `git status` there is no mention about `.git` folders. This also confirms `git ls-files` (which I've issued after `git add .` and `git commit`). But if I rename those `.git` folders e.g. to `.git.tmp` then `git status` start to "see" them. This behavior is also described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618950/git-ignore-git-folder) post. My git version is 2.25.1

Comment: You cannot ignore `.git/` of the [nested repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+nested+repository). It's built in right into `git`.

Comment: See my notes on submodules in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72964986/1256452).